# MySQL query eleminating duplicates from second table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two mysql tables: table_1 and table_2.

table_1:

```
| c_id | name |  email  |
|  1   | tom  | t@t.com |
```

table_2:

```
| a_id | c_id | address | street |
|  1   |  1   |   67    |  home  |
|  2   |  1   |   68    |  main  |
```

How to create mysql query that will select table_1.name, table_1.email, table_2.address and table_2.street returning only one record like:

```
| name | email   | address | street |
| tom  | t@t.com | 67      | home   |
```

Thanks for any suggestion.
Regards, T

Comment: What means "only one record". How is determined which of them should be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT table_1.name, table_1.email, table_2.address, table_2.street
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2
ON table_1.c_id = table_2.c_id
GROUP BY table_1.c_id
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbc52/2)

The `GROUP BY` will determine which column you want to use to group the results by. B.T.W. if you like the change the column head you can add `AS` followed by the column head name (`table_1.name AS "First name"`).

Table structure and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
    (`c_id` int, `name` varchar(3), `email` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO table_1
    (`c_id`, `name`, `email`)
VALUES
    (1, 'tom', 't@t.com')
;

CREATE TABLE table_2
    (`a_id` int, `c_id` int, `address` int, `street` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO table_2
    (`a_id`, `c_id`, `address`, `street`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 67, 'home'),
    (2, 1, 68, 'main')
;
```

If you like to limit the sql query to a certain person say tom `WHERE table_1.name LIKE 'Tom'`. Like so:

```
SELECT table_1.name, table_1.email, table_2.address, table_2.street
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2
ON table_1.c_id = table_2.c_id
WHERE table_1.name LIKE 'Tom'
GROUP BY table_1.c_id;
```

You can also use `=` but with LIKE you can use wildcards like `T%`

Comment: GROUP BY was the answer to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should use the SQL statement LEFT JOIN, for example

```
SELECT name, email, address, street
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.c_id=table2.c_id;
```

with the possible option WHERE name = 'tom'

Answer (score 0):

```
select table_1.name as name, table_1.email as email, table_2.address as address, table_2.street as street
from table_1 
left join table_2 on table_1.c_id = table_2.c_id
```